# PHP script interrupted by variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I'm trying to create a news system.

I'm implementing the ability to edit the news.

But there is a problem, if i change the picture the system sends the change to mysql. but If you change only the text, as the title or description but not edit the image changes are not updated to databse.

if not change the image, the change does not come. because the variable "file" is empty.

Code:

```
form: http://ideone.com/e62q84

action: http://ideone.com/q3noFc
```

see above url for my code.

there is a way to continue entering data even if the user chooses to leave the variable "file" empty?

Comment: all code is in 2 url.

Comment: You have syntax error here: update addd set name='$name', email='$email', age='$age', where id='$id'  (line 14, comma before WHERE). Remove it, and then test code again... It should work....

Comment: where is my Mind? thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happened because may be you check like `if(isset($_POST['file']))` so change this to any required filed i.e. `if(isset($_POST['title']))` or you can check with button also like `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`. Hope this help to you. If your issue is different then please add your code so we can identify the bug with your code.

Comment: bug found! error syntax on line 14.

Comment: @EugenioSegala ohhhh nice, You didn't put your code here. So i can't get what is the actual issue without code. :(

Comment: i put all code in 2 url on my post :)

Comment: @EugenioSegala I didn't see that.

Comment: http://ideone.com/e62q84 - http://ideone.com/q3noFc

Comment: @EugenioSegala ohk thanks but i said i didn't see that before you said. :)